# Does dropping my banner on the ground pull aggro?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does dropping your banner do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63635/what-does-dropping-your-banner-do)

You can hit the <kbd>G</kbd> key to drop your banner on the ground in game, however does this pull aggro?

I was wondering if you used it to mark a location, such as the pack of mobs you're going for, or a treasure goblin, if it would aggro them or not.

Comment: If a banner flew out of the sky with that force it would draw my attention.

Comment: @StrixVaria These questions are similiar, but I wouldn't say identical. None of the answers touch on the banners aggro drawing ability.

Comment: @Emerica bad answers are **not** reasons to ask new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not experienced any benefit from putting the banner anywhere. My best guess would be it's purely ornamental, unless you use it to mark a spot, or monster to attack for your party.

After testing it in a few spots and difficulties, I haven't noticed any visible benefit (no aggro help neither).

I'm sure there's others that can think of more *creative* uses.

**FOR EXAMPLE:** If you time it with their walking path, you can kill a chicken with it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for an answer, not a guess :)

Comment: Tested it, and it doesn't aggro.

Comment: Thanks :) If you edit your answer to include that information, I'll accept it

Answer (score 7):

Dropping the banner does nothing mechanical in-game. I do not know of a quote from Blizzard explicitly saying this, but there is reinforcing evidence:

**1) From the [D3 FAQ](http://reveal.diablo3.com/en_US/faq):**

> What is the banner and sigil?
>
> The banner is a customizable flag that shows off your achievements and progression when playing Diablo III. Your banner is displayed within the chat interface, in multiplayer games, and on the official Diablo III website. There are many individually customizable pieces of the banner, each of which represents a different section of the game...

This says that the banner is primarily a means to display your progress through the game and your accomplishments. Early in beta there were even [plans for more advanced banner progress](http://www.diablowiki.net/Banner) to show off your status.

There is also a [D3 blog post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/3549514) that indicates they intend the banner to be just a means of identifying players, and you can click a banner in town to teleport to that player.

**2) Forum threads:** there is discussion of this on the official forums, and the concensus is that banner dropping doesn't "do" anything (but lots of people wish it did!)

- [Thread 1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5150756781)
- [Thread 2](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4427709481)
- More: Google " site:us.battle.net diablo 3 drop banner"

**3) Documentation:** If the banner drop feature did something mechanically, Blizzard would document it, have 4 different tooltip popups pointing to it, mention it in their game guide, blog about it, post it to Twitter, and have airplanes fly around pulling banners mentioning it. My point is that Blizzard is very big on helping new players understand the game's features, and there are no signs that the banner does anything.

**4) Other games:** Finally, if the banner was for marking mobs or targets, I suspect they would follow the lead of WoW, which has a very clear and specific feature for marking raid targets. Blizzard loves to re-use features, so they would probably do something similar.

Comment: God. I'm not saying @lefke123 has a bad answer, but yours is like a lorebook here.

Comment: @RenoYeo Thank you, I try to get authoritative (or close to) sources. But lefke's answer has one thing mine doesn't: direct proof!